# How to upload csv file via jmeter in salesforce

Tags: ajax, file-upload, jmeter, xmlhttprequest, salesforce

I have recorded the scenario via blazemeter as i couldnt do it via jmeter. I am trying to upload file in salesforce app and i am getting 500error. I am able to correlate other parameters except the csv file. In csvAsSTring i am not sure what to put as its seems like encrypted. its not dynamic as i have tested it many times i am getting the same value.I am attaching screenshot. Any help how to upload the csv file would be appreciated.
I have tried multipart as well by giving exact location of file.

[1]:Highlighted part is where i need help https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOIkc.png

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to record a file upload request using JMeter normally you should copy the file you're trying to upload to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation, this way HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder[enter link description here](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) will be able to properly capture the request. See [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) article for more details.

Coming back to your question, if this `csvAsSTring` parameter value is not dynamic - it doesn't require correlation, the problem is somewhere else.

The fastest and the easiest way of identifying the problem is to capture the requests from the real browser and from JMeter using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) of [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and compare everything: URL, [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), body, etc.

The requests must be **exactly** the same (apart from dynamic values which need to be correlated)

Given you will send the same request you will get the same response so just figure out what is(are) the difference(s) and amend JMeter configuration to eliminate them

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have done file uploads in the past and everything was fine until i hit this scenario. I feel like file is base64 encoded when i am capturing it from browser. Its an AJAX request and jmeter is not capturing it i have tried in chrome IE and Firefox I cannot click when i try to upload it.

Comment: If you need to read CSV file from hard drive and encode it into Base64 - it can be done using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like `${__groovy(new File('/path/to/your/file.csv').bytes.encodeBase64().toString(),)}`. More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thank you so much Dmitri. Your help is really appreciated. I gave a second eye to the requests in Chrome Dev Tools and find out one of the correlation i was capturing from previous request was not correct. As both requests got the same parameters i was capturing from wrong request.Fixed the correlation and my request is all fine. Thanks again by emphasizing to find the difference.